# How to solve second-order cone programs efficiently?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

For a SOCP with many second-order cone constraints, e.g., $m = 10000$ in the following formulation, how to solve the problem efficiently?

$$\min_{x \in \Bbb R^n} f(x) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \| A_i x + b_i \|_2 \le c_i^T x + d_i, \quad \forall i=1,2,\dots,m$$

where $A_i \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$, $b_i \in \Bbb R^m$, $c_i \in \Bbb R^n$, $d_i \in \Bbb R$ are given. Does solving the corresponding dual problem help improve the computational efficiency?

Comment: Depends on the algorithm.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about how big $m$ and $n$ are.  The sparsity of the $A_{i}$ matrices is also potentially important.

Comment: If you're using an interior-point method, you basically are solving both the primal and the dual simultaneously. In fact, with a symmetric primal dual method, you'll basically approach the solutions to both problems with equal accuracy.

Comment: But the model you have offered here is so general that I would say there's really no reason to expect magic here. A big problem is just going to take a lot of time and memory to solve.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really takes a lot time for practical problems as I tried...